# Why is #undef not working for my function?

Tags: c++, undef

I defined something at the beginning:

```
#define noprint
```

Then I returned in my functions if it's defined:

```
void print()
{
    #ifdef noprint
        return;
    #else
        //do stuff
    #endif
}
```

Then in the main function:

```
main()
{
    #undef noprint
    print();
}
```

And it still doesn't work. How come?

Comment: `#define` is just textual substitution. Your definition of `print()` will have whatever the result is of performing those substitutions. When you invoke it in `main`, it uses that definition. It doesn't go back and recompile the definition of `print()` based on what it _would be_ if you'd defined things differently earlier on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are not variables. They are a simple text replacement tool. If you define, or undefine a macro, then that (un)definition has no effect on the source that precedes the macro. The function definition doesn't change after it has been defined.

Example:

```
#define noprint
// noprint is defined after the line above

void print()
{
    #ifdef noprint // this is true because noprint is defined
        return;
    #else
        //do stuff
    #endif
}

main()
{
    #undef noprint
// noprint is no longer after the line above
    print();
}
```

After pre-processing has finished, the resulting source looks like this:

```
void print()
{
    return;
}

main()
{
    print();
}
```

P.S. You must give all functions a return type. The return type of `main` must be `int`.

Comment: Yeah I have return 0 for main but I leave it out of the post because I never make it return anything else and it's implicit

Comment: @PupperGump `main` is special in that you don't need a return statement. But you must declare the return type for all functions.

Comment: Oh yeah I got that. If I don't the compiler warns me anyways.